# how to convert special string data to hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Hi i have some data that system send to me alternative like this:

```
"Screw:1,Bound:5,Hing:3"
"Bound:5,Screw:3,Hing:1"
"Bound:2,Screw:2"
```

how can i make this Hash?

```
{"Screw"=>6 ,"Bound"=>12, "Hing"=>4}
```

its probably add other key and value later , i hop solve this for me.

Comment: Split on commas, iterate, split on colon, use [0] as the hash key, [1] as the value. There are multiple ways this can be implemented; I'd use a hash where a key's default value is 0 then you can just continue to add [1] to it even if it didn't already exist, but it can be done manually as well. What have you tried so far, and what specific problem are you having?

Comment: Do you start with an array of three stings or is it one string containing three lines (i.e., separated by newlines)?

Comment: "how can i make this Hash?" – You write some code that does what you want. When you have problems with that code, you construct a [mre] that accurately reproduces your problem, and ask a focused question on [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [
  "Screw:1,Bound:5,Hing:3",
  "Bound:5,Screw:3,Hing:1",
  "Bound:2,Screw:2"
]
```

```
arr.flat_map { |s| s.split(',') }
   .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |s,h|
     k, v = s.split(':')
     h[k] += v.to_i
    end 
  #=> {"Screw"=>6, "Bound"=>12, "Hing"=>4}
```

Step 1

```
arr.flat_map { |s| s.split(',') }
  #=>["Screw:1", "Bound:5", "Hing:3", "Bound:5", "Screw:3", "Hing:1",
  #   "Bound:2", "Screw:2"]
```

See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument and no block. The argument is called the *default value*, which is here zero. If `h` has been defined `h = Hash.new(0)`, and `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value (and does not modify the hash). `h[k] += v.to_i` expands to

```
h[k] = h[k] + v.to_i
```

so if `h` does not have a key `k` this becomes

```
h[k] = 0 + v.to_i
```

---

Alternatively, one could write the following.

```
arr.flat_map { |s| s.split(/:|,/) }
   .each_slice(2)
   .with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k,v),h| h[k] += v.to_i }
  #=> {"Screw"=>6, "Bound"=>12, "Hing"=>4}
```

Steps 1 and 2

```
a = arr.flat_map { |s| s.split(/:|,/) }
  #=> ["Screw", "1", "Bound", "5", "Hing", "3", "Bound", "5",
  #    "Screw", "3", "Hing", "1", "Bound", "2", "Screw", "2"]
e = a.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Screw", "1", "Bound", "5", "Hing", "3",
  #                  "Bound", "5", "Screw", "3", "Hing", "1",
  #                  "Bound", "2", "Screw", "2"]:each_slice(2)>
```

The elements generated by the enumerator `e` can be seen as follows:

```
e.entries
  #=> [["Screw", "1"], ["Bound", "5"], ["Hing", "3"], ["Bound", "5"],
  #    ["Screw", "3"], ["Hing", "1"], ["Bound", "2"], ["Screw", "2"]]
```

Comment: For those of us with more esoteric tendencies: `arr.reduce({}) {_1.merge(_2.enum_for(:scan,/(\w+):(\d+)/).with_object({}){|(a,b),h| h[a]=b.to_i}){|_,o,n| o+n}}` or `arr.to_s.enum_for(:scan,/(\w+):(\d+)/).with_object(Hash.new(0)){_2[_1[0]]+=_1[1].to_i}`

Comment: @engineersmnky, imo, `_1` and `_2` look like they've been whooped with an ugly stick. Why is it I knew who authored that comment after reading "esoteric tendencies"?

Comment: I totally agree unless we are code golfing numbered block parameters really detracts from the core ruby philosophy of readability. That being said I do love a question that allows for the rare usage of `enum_for`

Answer (score 1):

A good way would be too loop through all of the entries and update the hash depending on the entries that get found.
The following will do it for you.

```
str = "Screw:1,Bound:5,Hing:3"

output = Hash.new(0)

str.split(",").each do |entry|
  key = entry.split(":")
  output[key[0]] += key[1].to_i
end
```

Just modify it so that it handles multiple strings correctly, depending on how they are fed to you in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the data is CSV so I'd opt to use a CSV parser to avoid possible encoding issues

```rb
require 'csv'

def parse input
  Hash[CSV.parse_line(input).map { |pair| pair.split(":") }]
end
```